# Trying to weight paint a shoulder so that the arm doesn't clip into itself. Any tips?

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, rigify, vertex-weights

So I purchased a model and rigify refuses to work when parenting the mesh to the meta rig. I think it's because the arm clips into the armpit creating a vertex hell. So I made a quick arm rig to rotate the arms into an A pose, but this is my first time weight painting manually, and it's deforming like hot garbage. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? I have attached the blend file (I think?)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You also need to have bones for the body and shoulders. Without it, the arms have nothing to blend. That's why in your image, parts with the lowest weight value still follow the arm.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm confused at how you got the shoulder bone to move when you move the arm though, I thought the weight painting only affects the vertices and not other bones? Would it be possible for you to post that edited blend file so I can learn from what you did?

Comment: You're welcome @Blith :)
Oh no, I animated the shoulder bone manually. It's not from weight painting or anything. You know when you raise your arms, your shoulder bone is also moving. So I think it's only natural to animate the shoulder bone too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to smooth out the weights between the shoulder and arm. The blur brush in weight paint mode can work quite well for this for this.

The Blur brush is a separate tool from the standard brushes and can be found in the left hand side tool menu.

You may also need to add a root/body bone and weight the stationary vertices to that, then blend between them. Turning on [auto-normalise](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/tool_settings/options.html) can help when blurring between multiple existing groups, as it will automatically adjust the weights of the others.

Additionally, check to see if your armature modifier is using vertex weights or bone envelopes. Don't envelopes.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see the blur brush though. I only see draw, add, subtract, mix etc

Comment: @Blith Edited for location of blur brush

Comment: Oh nice, thank you! I still seem to have the issue though, I faded each color into each other with the blur, I blurred the edges and faded it out to 0, but I still get a slight fissure where the shoulder cuts into itself. Edited my post for a picture

Comment: It looks like it isn't quite respecting your weight painting for some reason. Can you add a picture of the modifier stack?

Comment: The modifier stack only has the armature mod, nothing else. Is the model maybe too dense?

Comment: Also am I supposed to have auto Normalize on when weight painting?

Comment: @Blith auto-normalise is not going to help if you only have one bone. Check the armature modifier settings, it looks like you may have bone envelopes enabled. Its definitely a fairly dense mesh, but that shouldn't be a problem here

Comment: Nope, Bone envelopes is off, it makes it even more wonky if I turn it on lol. Maybe the bone is in the wrong place so it is rotating weird??

Comment: try adding a second bone for all the stationary vertices and blending between that and the moving one